# Why can't I use oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user ... but I can use oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user ...?

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Most examples out there use something like:

```
$ oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin admin
```

however, if I run it I get:

```
$ oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin admin
error: unknown command "add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin
```

with `oadm` version:

```
$oadm version
oadm v1.4.0-rc1+b4e0954
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
features: Basic-Auth

Server https://192.168.64.18:8443
openshift v1.3.2
kubernetes v1.3.0+52492b4
```

However, using:

```
oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin admin
```

**does** work.

I have not seen (could have missed it...) any documentation on the OpenShift Origin documentation or anywhere else that mentions when one should be used over the other, or if the former has been deprecated etc..

I did find [this issue (#1845)](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/issues/1845) but not much clarification.

Can anyone please clarify...

Comment: Probably you don't have oadm command in your local, but you have the oc command. You can try to connect to the openshift master, for example through ssh with root permissions or similar and try to run the oadm command here.